# How to check if a value is NOT anywhere in a Lua table?

Tags: lua

I am pretty new to lua so please excuse me if this question is too basic. I was wondering if there is a good way to check if a value is not in a lua table. Something like:

```lua
if 5 ~= t[1] or 5 ~= t[2] or 5 ~= t[3] ... then end
```

but less stupid.

This

```lua
for i,v in ipairs(t) do
   if  5 ~= v then
   end
end
```

does not really work because I want to check if it does not show up anywhere in the table rather than if it equals to any given value.

Probably the only somewhat viable solution I could think of so far would be something like

```lua
check = 0
for i,v in ipairs(t) do
   if  5 == v then
   check = 1
   end
end

if check == 0 then end
```

but that still looks kind of cumbersome...

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to check whether an item exists in array, you better keep a hash map to that array. This is obviously ineffective to go through the whole (or part of the) array for each check. I'll suggest you to create the mapping and only after, do your checks. Example:

```
local function array_map(array)
  local map = {}
  for _, item in ipairs(array) do
    map[item] = true
  end
  return map
end

local array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
local arr_map = array_map(array)

if arr_map[1] then 
  print("The array has item 1")
end

if not arr_map[10] then
  print("Item 10 is not part of the array")
end
```

This is how you get your tests in constant time of `ϑ(1)` + `n` once for the map build.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if a value is in a table you have to compare every table value to your value until you find your first match.

```
for k,v in pairs(myTable) do
  if v == searchValue then
    print("Found one!")
    break
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that `ipairs` only works for tables with consecutive indices 1-n.
If you want to check any table elements use `pairs`.